# Get selected info from scatter-series with scatterPlot

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I implemented [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-series.html) from `dc.js examples` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c94sddjm/1/).

Also, I added `.brushOn(true)` option to my chart. After my brushing, I need to get selected information.

My filter function:

```
.on('filtered', function(chart){
    console.log(runDimension.top(Infinity));
})
```

Unfortunately, I can't call `onFiltered` event with brushing.

I added one more listener for `brushend` event and get here empty object:

```
var b = chart.brush();
b.on('brushend.custom', function() {
    console.log(runDimension.top(Infinity));
});
```

How can I get selected information with `brushOn(true)`?

P.S I use [this](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/tree/gazal-grouped-bar) branch of dc.js with version 2.1.0-dev, because I need grouped charts.

Comment: `.on('filtered', ...)` looks right to me. Do you mean the event is not fired when the chart is brushed?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use debug and break point but current event is not fired when the chart is brushed